# How to fix the controller new function rendering functionality

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. I having problem in payslip controller. Using this we can create payslip for each employee.the problem is once the condition is true it shows like payslip was created already.if its fail it again  render the whole form.

In controller

```
def new
@teacher_payslip = TeacherPayslip.new
@teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
if params[:date] and TeacherPayslip.find_by_teacher_id(params[:teacher_id]).present?
  @old_salary_date = TeacherPayslip.find_by_teacher_id(params[:teacher_id]).salary_date
  @a = @old_salary_date.strftime("%b%Y")
  @new_salary_date = params[:date].to_date
  @b = @new_salary_date.strftime("%b%Y")
  if @a == @b
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

end

Js file

```
$('body').on("change","#teacher_payslip_salary_date",function(){
  var month = $('#teacher_payslip_salary_date').val();
  var teacher = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')[0];
  var url = '/teacher_payslips/new?date='+ month +'&'+teacher
  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
        $('#payslip').html(data);
   }
  });
})
```

[image]

Please Guide Me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller's action to:

```
def new
@teacher_payslip = TeacherPayslip.new
@teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
if params[:date] and TeacherPayslip.find_by_teacher_id(params[:teacher_id]).present?
  @old_salary_date = TeacherPayslip.find_by_teacher_id(params[:teacher_id]).salary_date
  @a = @old_salary_date.strftime("%b%Y")
  @new_salary_date = params[:date].to_date
  @b = @new_salary_date.strftime("%b%Y")
  if @a == @b
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  else
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

Comment: I am having doubt how to get month and year alone from [Thu, 10 Oct 2013, Wed, 06 Nov 2013].which is in array format

Comment: Use strptime method of the string type of ruby.. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#strptime-method